# How to avoid having to type password every time rsync is run in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, ssh, passwords, rsync

In a bash script, I have several rsync statements.  Every rsync will prompt for typing password, and defeats very much the automation of doing the job using a script.  How to improve this? The destination path of rsync statements are either network drive connected via SAMBA or on a SSH server.

Comment: What OS are you running that script in? From the comments below, I guess OS X, but I wouldn’t want to answer without you specifying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Generate a SSH key pair](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-keyc/index.html), upload the public half to the server, and [put the private half in the local agent](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-keyc2/).

Comment: What if the server is not SSH accessible?  In Mac OS X 10.6.8, I connect to `smb://host.com/mydir` via Finder (Go -> Connect to Server menu option).

Comment: SMB URLs accept a username and password.

Comment: Do you mean put my user name and password explicitly in my Bash script like `smb://foouser:bar@host.com/mydir`?

Answer (score 1):

The generic method for repeating the same string in shell is:

```
yes "string" ¦ command args
```

Or for non-repetitive, complex string:

```
echo -e "first\nsecond\n..." ¦ command args
```